# removing excess paint on a nick touchup

Tags: paint, body

i dropped a spark plug on the fender of an $8000.00 paint job. i touched up the 2 nicks ,but have a little excess paint outside of nicks. any suggestions on how to remove the excess? i used a product called rub out or rub off  after touching up road rash on my fender flairs at the wheels. worked great but i have misplaced it & don,t remember who made it. any help would be grateful. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use 3000 grit sandpaper, then you need a rubbing compound to take out those swirl marks.

Buy meguirs swirl remover it is an amazing compound you can only get it at professional paint supply or lordco ( from Canada) or a parts store it comes in a brown bottle.

This is the professional way.  More professional is probably use 800 grit 1000 grit 1500 2000 then 3000. then swirl remover or cut polish then polish.